# Jquery help needed

Tags: jquery

```
$(".bottomnavinvest").stop().animate({'bottom' : '40px'}, 800, 'easeInBounce',  
    function(){                    
        $(".bottomnavinvest").hide();                         
    });
}

$(".demolink").click(function(){
    if ($(".bottomnavinvest").is(':visible')); {
        bottomnavinvestout();
    }
    $("#contentinner").children().fadeOut(1000, function(){
        $('#demoreel').fadeIn(1000, function(){
            bottomnavdemoin();
        });
    });
    return false
});

$(".investlink").click(function(){
    if ($(".bottomnavdemo").is(':visible')); {
        bottomnavdemoout();
    };
    $("#contentinner").children().fadeOut(1000, function(){
        $('#investment').fadeIn(1000, function(){
            bottomnavinvestin();
        });
    });
    return false
});
```

The demo in and demo out functions are the same as the invest in and invest out functions,

I am trying to bounce a secondary nav bar up then hide it, fadeout then in new content, then bounce down a different navbar on appropriate button clicks

It is fading out, then in the new content only to fade that out then in again.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong or how i can improve on what I am doing?

Cheers
Ben

Comment: oops, that somehow got cut at the top:

        function bottomnavinvestin(){

    $(".bottomnavinvest").show('', function(){

    $(".bottomnavinvest").stop().animate({'bottom' : '0px'} , 800,
     'easeOutBounce');

    });

    }


    function bottomnavinvestout(){

    $(".bottomnavinvest").stop().animate({'bottom' : '40px'} ,  
   800,'easeInBounce' ,  

    function(){    
                
    $(".bottomnavinvest").hide(); 
                        
    });

    }

Comment: You should edit the question instead of adding some stuff in comments

And while editing - try to make the problem description more understandable ;)

Comment: Please include some HTML or a demo page... it would make answering your question much easier.

Answer (score 0):

After formatting your question it's even more easy to see:

```
$(".bottomnavinvest").stop().animate({'bottom' : '40px'}, 800, 'easeInBounce',  
    function(){                    
        $(".bottomnavinvest").hide();                         
    });
}

$(".demolink").click(function(){
    if ($(".bottomnavinvest").is(':visible')); { //THIS ';' BREAKS THE CODE, REMOVE IT !!!
        bottomnavinvestout();
    }
    $("#contentinner").children().fadeOut(1000, function(){
        $('#demoreel').fadeIn(1000, function(){
            bottomnavdemoin();
        });
    });
    return false
});

$(".investlink").click(function(){
    if ($(".bottomnavdemo").is(':visible')); {   //THIS ';' BREAKS THE CODE, REMOVE IT !!!
        bottomnavdemoout();
    };                                           //THIS ';' NOT NEEDED, REMOVE IT !!!
    $("#contentinner").children().fadeOut(1000, function(){
        $('#investment').fadeIn(1000, function(){
            bottomnavinvestin();
        });
    });
    return false
});
```

Remove all those **extra** `;` in your code, and it should work.